# Update database feature not working in Publish Web dialog in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, webdeploy, database-deployment

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Forms application under Visual Studio 2012. I'm using Web Deploy and Publish Web dialog for application deploy. I'm trying to deploy a database schema using the Update database feature. I entered a connection string pointing to remote SQL Server. If I click the "Test connection" button Visual Studio says test connection is succeeded.

[image]

Then I go to Preview tab and click the Preview database link.

[image]

And in the opened window I have the message

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not generate deployment script.
>   Unable to connect to target server.   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.)

Other project files are deployed normally. I'm able to connect to SQL Server using SQL Server Management Service. But why the database could not be updated? I tried to disable server firewall - with no luck.

- Visual Studio Professional 2012
- SQL Server 2012
- Web Deploy 3.0

**Update**

All works fine if I use SQL Server Authentication with the `sa` login instead of Windows Authentication in connection string for DatabaseEntitiesRaw. But Windows Authentication works fine for SSMS, and I want to use it since I'm deploying only from computers within my company's domain. Is it true that dbDacFx doesn't work with Windows Authentication?

Comment: What happens if you just deploy instead of preview?

Comment: @aclear16 The same error in the output window: 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4377,5): Error ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD: Web deployment task failed. (Could not deploy package. Unable to connect to target server...

Comment: You probably need to enable EF Code first migration. Use the link next the triangle with the exclamation point in it.

Comment: @aclear16 I'm trying to deploy this database as a stand-alone one, without any connection to the EF, since I'm using a Data First approach.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. Can you email me so that I can work more closely with you to solve this? My email is sayedha[at]{MicrosoftDOTcom}

Comment: Problem was in the authentication method. See the update section in the initial question.

Comment: You cannot use Windows Auth because this is flowing through MSDeploy and the Web Management Service.

Answer (score 3):

Deploy script runs from AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE user, so you have to add this user to SQL server. Do not foget to add db_owner role for the user.